# Remove duplicate values in string array?

Tags: ballerina

There is a string array containing a number of strings in which multiple strings resemble each other. The requirement is to remove duplicates in the array.

Input :

```
["Anne", "Jane", "John", "Jane", "Ivan", "Peter", "Anne"]
```

Output:

```
["Anne","Jane","John","Ivan","Peter"]
```

It seems no langlib function to achieve this directly.
How to remove duplicate strings in an array using Ballerina?

Answer (score 4):

Here are two ways of removing duplicates from a string array.

**Method 1**: Using indexOf method of [lang.array](https://lib.ballerina.io/ballerina/lang.array/0.0.0/functions#indexOf)

**Method 2**: Using keys method of [lang.map](https://lib.ballerina.io/ballerina/lang.map/0.0.0/functions#keys)

Sample code is as follows.

```
import ballerina/io;

// Method 1
function getUniqueValues(string[] names) returns string[] {
    string[] uniqueNames = [];
    foreach string name in names {
        if uniqueNames.indexOf(name) is () {
            uniqueNames.push(name);
        }
    }
    return uniqueNames;
}

//Method 2
function getUniqueValuesUsingMap(string[] names) returns string[] {
    map<()> mapNames = {};
    foreach var name in names {
        mapNames[name] = ();
    }
    return mapNames.keys();
}

public function main() {
    string[] duplicatedStrings = ["Anne", "Jane", "John", "Jane", "Ivan", "Peter", "Anne"];

    //Using Method 1
    io:println(getUniqueValues(duplicatedStrings));

    //Using Method 2
    io:println(getUniqueValuesUsingMap(duplicatedStrings));

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the [**`.some()` langlib function**](https://lib.ballerina.io/ballerina/lang.array/0.0.0/functions#some) of Ballerina arrays, this could be achieved as following.

```
public function main() {
    string[] strArr = ["Anne", "Jane", "John", "Jane", "Ivan", "Jane", "Peter", "Anne"];

    _ = strArr.some(function (string s) returns boolean {
           int? firstIndex = strArr.indexOf(s);
           int? lastIndex = strArr.lastIndexOf(s);
           if (firstIndex != lastIndex) {
              _ = strArr.remove(<int>lastIndex);
           }

           // Returning true, if the end of the array is reached.
           if (firstIndex == (strArr.length() - 1)) {
              return true;
           }

        return false;
    });

    io:println(strArr);
}
```

Since the `.some()` langlib function is used to check if at least a single member in the array follows the given condition, it could be used to determine if we've reached the end of the array and prevent the **Index Out of Bound Exception**.

Within the function that is passed as the parameter of the `.some()` langlib function, we'd be removing only the last instance of any duplicate value. When reached to the end of the array, all the duplicate values would be removed.